# Regex to exclude word inside curly braces

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a variable {{data.something}}

And "something" will take a different value each time.

I want a Regex that matches curly braces + "data." so I can access "something" easily

This sounds easy but I can't make it work...

I've got this to get what's inside the curly braces, but I'm stuck now

```
   \{{(.*?)\}}
```

If I do:

```
matched_data = /\{{(.*?)\}}/.match("{{data.something}}")
```

I end up with

```
  matched_data = "data.something".
```

What I want is to end up with just "something"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you be more specific please? A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could help you to have a better answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry the question was pretty clear to me... I'll try and edit it

Comment: Does `matched_data = "{{data.something}}"[/\{\{data\.(.*?)\}\}/]` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be generic about ignoring anything ahead of the dot you can use a non-capturing group (start a group with "`?:`"):

```
matched_data = /{{(?:.*?)\.(.*?)}}/.match("{{foo.bar}}")
puts matched_data[1]
```

will print

```
bar
```

Also you don't need to escape the curly braces in this case because they don't follow a pattern.

Comment: Amazing, that works perfectly!! The solutions above and below were returning almost the right thing but not quite (something weird happening with curly braces)

Comment: In that case please could you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

If you include `data.` in the expression outside of your capture group the captured value will be “something”. Is this what you're after?

```rb
matched_data = /\{{data\.(.+)\}}/.match("{{data.something}}")
puts matched_data[1] #=> "something"
```

Answer (score -1):

If I hunderstood your question you need a grouping in your regex and then acces the group.

The method `Regexp#match` return a [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/MatchData.html) object.

You can access a group  specified in the regex through the returned MatchData object.

```rb
matched_data = /{{(.+)\.(.+)?}}/.match("{{data.something}}") 
puts matched_data[1] == 'data'
# true
puts matched_data[2] == 'something'
# true
```